# Detect mail adress in textbox or richtextbox and open outlook

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with data from customers, that are entered by the user, something like an agenda...

In the form I have some text fields that ask for mail adress from the customers, I would like that when the user clicks in the textbox text, it automatically opens outlook with a new sent mail tab with the selected adress, I've seen it in a lot of websites, but I didn't find anything about doing it in a windows form.

And if there's a way only with richtextbox, there's no problem, since I can change the textbox a richtextbox.

BTW, I'm using vb.net

Comment: Just run "mailto:[email address]"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Typically, you just add a mailto: link.  You cannot force Outlook to open.  When the user clicks on the mailto, their default mail client will open.  If Outlook is their default, then it will open, if it is THunderbird or Gmail or something else, that is what they will be prompted to use.

Comment: @AaronRumford `You cannot force Outlook to open.` I beg to differ, you can including starting it with the email address. `Interop` allows this...

Comment: @zaggler Please provide a code example of forcing Outlook to launch from a webpage.  Especially when it is not installed.

Comment: @AaronRumford who said anything about a webpage? This is tagged `vb.net` not anything related to web based. A hint would be `RichTextBox` this isn't available in `asp.net` as it's a Windows Form only control. There are other forms of a RichTextBox, but Im afraid this isn't one of those...Oh one more thing `I've seen it in a lot of websites, but I didn't find anything about doing it in a windows form.` does this mention webpages, I ***dont think so***... Either the OP is very confused or doesn't really know what he needs...

Comment: On another note; `JavaScript` and `ActiveX` can be used from the web to launch `Outlook` if it's installed...